# «Задайте их и посмотрите...» Ставить ли запятую перед И?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

**Задайте их и посмотрите...**  Ставить ли запятую перед И?

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вы] **Задайте их** (вопросы, цели, параметры) **и посмотри́те...** ( Что сделайте?)

Определенно-личное предложение, в котором однородные сказуемые выражены повелительной формой глагола, соединены одиночным союзом **и**.  Запятая не нужна.

*Зажгите свечу и установите ее на ровную поверхность.

Прочитайте текст и ответьте на вопросы.*

Answer (score 0):

Нет, зачем же? Это однородные члены, соединённые одиночным союзом И.

Answer (score 0):

**Задайте их и посмотрите...**

Это однородные односоставные (определенно-личные) предложения, для которых действуют те же правила, что и для однородных членов.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

3. Запятая перед соединительным и разделительным союзами в сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, если в его состав в качестве частей входят:

**односоставные неопределенно-личные предложения** (если мыслится **один и тот же производитель действия**).

Что касается **определенно-личных предложений**, то они всегда указывают на конкретное лицо (1-е или 2-е), что по сути является **общим элементом**, соединяющим предложения при наличии одиночного союза И.